# How I can rename txt files according to first line of text file?

Tags: command-line, shell, batch-rename, nppexec, nppscript

I have multiple .txt files and I want to rename them as first line text they contains.

First line in every text file is some number and text Example
ParagraphL23
I want my text file to be renamed as ParagraphL23.txt

And I want to do this on all my files, 30 of them.

I have Ubuntu and notepad++

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mv oldname.txt `head -1 oldname.txt`.txt
```

Comment: [Quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).